# viewWillAppear(_:) viewDidDisappear(_:) View SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to fetch the data from on `viewWillAppear(_:)`

Is there any equal method or modifier available in `SwiftUI`
also any modifier for `viewDidDisappear(_:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure there are

> ```
> @available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
> extension View {
>
>     /// Adds an action to perform when this view appears.
>     ///
>     /// - Parameter action: The action to perform. If `action` is `nil`, the
>     ///   call has no effect.
>     /// - Returns: A view that triggers `action` when this view appears.
>     @inlinable public func onAppear(perform action: (() -> Void)? = nil) -> some View
>
>
>     /// Adds an action to perform when this view disappears.
>     ///
>     /// - Parameter action: The action to perform. If `action` is `nil`, the
>     ///   call has no effect.
>     /// - Returns: A view that triggers `action` when this view disappears.
>     @inlinable public func onDisappear(perform action: (() -> Void)? = nil) -> some View
>
> }
> ```

Comment: Isn't `onAppear()` same as `viewDidAppear()` not `viewWillAppear()`?

Comment: @jonye._.jin No, onAppear is called when a view is inserted into view hierarchy - it might be far away from appearing on screen, if ever at all.